# Tense "was breaking" doubt

Tags: tense

> Everyday last week my aunt was breaking a plate.

Is the tense correct in this sentence?

This is the answer my teacher gave. Could someone tell me why "was breaking" is used here?

Comment: http://www.englisch-hilfen.de/en/grammar/past_prog.htm

Comment: Your teacher is almost certainly not a native speaker. There's nothing *grammatically* wrong with the sentence, but it's an extremely unlikely thing to say. The most likely meaning would be that the aunt spent time (unsuccessfully) trying to break *the **same** plate* every day, no matter how weird that is at the level of semantics. If she's been (successfully) breaking a *different* plate every day, you'd say *"Every day last week my aunt **broke** a plate"*.

Comment: She said something like.. Everyday s meant to be continuous so was breaking.. But what you said also makes sense..

Comment: You could say, "My aunt was breaking *plates* [plural] and spilling glasses all last week; she was a real terror in the kitchen."

Comment: @ Tim Romano.. Sorry but I can't change the sentence cause it's a fill in the blanks question with was breaking the blanks

Comment: You can't use continuous action because each day was a discrete day. Also, "Everyday" is incorrect. It should be "Every day".  "Everyday" is an adjective.

Comment: So the "everyday"  in the sentence doesn't affect the tense?

Comment: "Everyday" is incorrect. The sun's rising is an everyday occurrence. It is an adjective. The train runs every day. Every day she broke a plate. To answer your question, "Every day" does indeed affect the tense. Because the action was happening on EACH day, i.e. it was a daily occurrence, you cannot use a *continuous* tense, as you could if you had said "all last week".

Comment: If it was "all last week"  then there 'all' is not adjective but here "everyday"  s adjective... Am I right?

Answer (score 3):

The website is complaining about "extended discussions in comments" so I will do this as an answer.

> I was going to English classes all summer.
>
> I went to an English class each day this summer.

Do you understand why the single word "Everyday" cannot be used? It is an adjective and must modify a noun. It means "not unusual, common, quotidien".

**Rain is an everyday thing during the monsoon.**

"Every day" on the other hand is a temporal phrase that means "On each day".

So it does affect the tense. You need a simple past to represent an action that took place at a discrete time (each day).

Whereas "all last week" would mean "continuously throughout the week" and then you could use "was breaking".

ADDENDUM:
To answer the question posed in the comment, *Is there any problem if the "was going" is replaced by 'went' and vice versa?*

Yes, there is a problem if we replace "was going" with "went".

INCORRECT: I *was going* to an English class each day this summer.

Why is it incorrect? Because of "each day".

**Each morning last summer, I awoke at sunrise.**

INCORRECT: Each morning last summer, I was awaking at sunrise.

CORRECT: Last summer, I was awaking at sunrise, but these days I feel quite tired, and am unable to get out of bed earlier than 7AM.

Comment: Isn't everyday the synonym for all...

Comment: Could you explain it a little more... In the sentences which u gave.. Is there any problem if the "was going"  is replaced by 'went' and vice versa

Comment: It might be helpful to look at the [definition of "everyday"](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/everyday), which is a word that is distinct in meaning from the two words "every" and "day".

Comment: "Everyday" (one word) is NOT a synonym for all; it is an adjective that means "ordinary". See this definition: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/everyday

Answer (score 0):

*Everyday last week my aunt was breaking a plate*

"was breaking" is repeating.

Well, implied repeatedly or a new each day, yet the sentence is correct. 
I'd like to hear the situation here, maybe the teacher is not as foreign as it seems.

Comment: Please take the [site tour](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) before proceeding further. This is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, and has particular guidelines and conventions for participation.